# ArithmeticException in C# code after calling C function from dll

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, arithmeticexception

I have code written in C# and a DLL written in C. I'm trying to call functions from the DLL. For example, header file for DLL in C:

```
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef Perspectiva_DLLUnitH
#define Perspectiva_DLLUnitH
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#define DLL_EXPORT __export __stdcall
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif
UCHAR DLL_EXPORT Init(ULONG TerminalID, CHAR *AzsNo, ULONG *Len);
...
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

And this is how i'm working with this DLL in C#:

```
static class Pers
{
   [DllImport("Perspectiva_DLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
   public static extern byte Init(uint TerminalID, string AzsNo, out uint Len);
   ...
}

...

uint Len = Convert.ToUInt32(AzsNo.Text.Length);
Pers.Init(Convert.ToUInt32(TerminalID.Text), AzsNo.Text, out Len);
```

Function Init works correctly and returns the result. But after the call if I'm trying to do any action with interface, for example, change tab, or just clicking the textbox, i'm getting an exception: `ArithmeticException`.

I can't understand where the error is in my code.

Exception details:

```
System.ArithmeticException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024362
  Message=Переполнение или потеря точности в арифметической операции.
  Source=WindowsBase
  StackTrace:
       в System.Windows.Size..ctor(Double width, Double height)
       в System.Windows.Documents.AdornerLayer.InvalidateAdorner(AdornerInfo adornerInfo)
       в System.Windows.Documents.AdornerLayer.UpdateElementAdorners(UIElement element)
       в System.Windows.Documents.AdornerLayer.UpdateAdorner(UIElement element)
       в System.Windows.Documents.AdornerLayer.Add(Adorner adorner, Int32 zOrder)
       в System.Windows.Documents.CaretElement.EnsureAttachedToView()
       в System.Windows.Documents.CaretElement.Update(Boolean visible, Rect caretRectangle, Brush caretBrush, Double opacity, Boolean italic, CaretScrollMethod scrollMethod, Double scrollToOriginPosition)
       в System.Windows.Documents.TextSelection.UpdateCaretStateWorker(Object o)
       в System.Windows.Documents.TextSelection.UpdateCaretState(CaretScrollMethod caretScrollMethod)
       в System.Windows.Documents.TextSelection.EnsureCaret(Boolean isBlinkEnabled, Boolean isSelectionActive, CaretScrollMethod scrollMethod)
       в System.Windows.Documents.TextSelection.System.Windows.Documents.ITextSelection.UpdateCaretAndHighlight()
       в System.Windows.Documents.TextEditor.OnGotKeyboardFocus(Object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
       в System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.TextBoxBase.OnGotKeyboardFocus(KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
       в System.Windows.UIElement.OnGotKeyboardFocusThunk(Object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
       в System.Windows.Input.KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
       в System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
       в System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
       в System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
       в System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       в System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
       в System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
       в System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
       в System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
       в System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.ChangeFocus(DependencyObject focus, Int32 timestamp)
       в System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.TryChangeFocus(DependencyObject newFocus, IKeyboardInputProvider keyboardInputProvider, Boolean askOld, Boolean askNew, Boolean forceToNullIfFailed)
       в System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.Focus(DependencyObject focus, Boolean askOld, Boolean askNew, Boolean forceToNullIfFailed)
       в System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.Focus(IInputElement element)
       в System.Windows.UIElement.Focus()
       в System.Windows.Documents.TextEditorMouse.MoveFocusToUiScope(TextEditor This)
       в System.Windows.Documents.TextEditorMouse.OnMouseDown(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
       в System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.TextBoxBase.OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
       в System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseDownThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
       в System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
       в System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
       в System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
       в System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
       в System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       в System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
       в System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
       в System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
       в System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
       в System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
       в System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
       в System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       в System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       в MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       в MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
       в System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       в MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       в System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       в MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       в MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
       в System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
       в System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
       в System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
       в System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
       в System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
       в System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
       в System.Windows.Application.Run()
       в Perspectiva_test.App.Main() в d:\тнп\test_codes\Perspectiva_test\Perspectiva_test\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:строка 0
       в System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       в System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       в Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       в System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       в System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Is that calling convention right?

Comment: It would help if you'd show us where the exception occurs. From your description it might not even be in the code you posted.

Comment: leppie, calling conventions right. I've tryed to use cdecl in c# without __stdcall in C. Result is the same. Dirk, wait a moment

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This usually occurs if the runtime system of the C dll changes FPU flags. You need to reset those after calling the function similar to this:

```
[DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
extern static uint _controlfp(uint newcw,uint mask);

const uint _MCW_EM=0x0008001f;
const uint _EM_INVALID=0x00000010;

public static void FixFPU() {
{
  _controlfp(_MCW_EM, _EM_INVALID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem calling COM class from C#.
The solution was to make interop call from ThreadPool thread, not UI thread, using async delagate. I guess changing the thread saves FPU state

```
BankOperation op = new BankOperation(DoBankAuthorize);
// BankOperation is delegate, DoBankAuthorize - the real method calling COM class
IAsyncResult ar = op.BeginInvoke(sum, null, null);
bparams = op.EndInvoke(ar);
```